# update specific lines in text file C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to  update specific lines in text file using this  condition:
if line contain **Word-to-search** remove only the next space

using the blew code :

```
using (System.IO.TextReader tr = File.OpenText((@"d:\\My File3.log")))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    string[] items = line.Trim().Split(' ');

                    foreach (var s in items)
                    {

                        if (s == "a" || s == "b")


                            s = s.Replace(" ", "");
                        using (StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\\My File3.log"))  

                        tw.WriteLine(s);
```

my file is llike :

k l m

x y z a c

b d a w

the update file shold be like :

k l m

x y z **ac**

**bd** **aw**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by:

```
...
if (s == "a" || s == "b"){
if (s == "a") 
 s = s.Replace("a ", "a");
if (s == "b") 
s = s.Replace("b ", "b");
using (StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\\My File3.log"))  
 tw.WriteLine(s);
}
...
```

SAMPLE:

```
 string test="a c";
 test =test.Replace("a ", "a");
 Console.WriteLine(test);
```

OUTPUT:
ac

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
string path = @"d:\My File3.log"; 

var data = File
  .ReadLines(path)
  .Select(line => line
     .Replace("a ", "a")
     .Replace("b ", "b"))
  .ToList(); // Materialization, since we have to write back to the same file

File.WriteAllLines(path, data);
```

In *general case*, e.g.

> if line contain **Word-to-search**

means that `a` and `b` should be *words* (`b` within `abc` is not the word we are looking for):

```
"abc a b c a" -> "abc abc a"
```

try using *regular expressions*:

```
  string[] words = new string[] { "a", "b" };
  string pattern = 
    @"\b(" + string.Join("|", 
     words.Select(item => Regex.Escape(item))) + 
    @")\s";

  var data = File
   .ReadLines(path)
   .Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, pattern, m => m.Groups[1].Value))
   .ToList();

  File.WriteAllLines(path, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
....

while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
{

    using (StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\\My File3.log"))
    string st = line.Replace("a ", "a").Replace("b ", "b");//just add additional .Replace() here
    tw.WriteLine(st); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, I think, is here:

```
if (s == "a" || s == "b")
                        s = s.Replace(" ", "");
```

In order to satisfy your `if` condition, `string` `s` is necessarily without any spaces in it. Your code, therefore, does nothing.

```
if(s == "a" ||  s == "b")
         foreach(var s2 in items)
         {
            if(items.IndexOf(s2) > items.IndexOf(s) && s2 == " ")
               s2 == string.Empty;
               break;
         }
```

The `break` exists to ensure we only replace the next space, not all spaces following the character.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider a temporary variable just before foreach loop

```
int temp = 0;
foreach(var s in items)
{
    if (temp == 0)
            {
                if (s == "a" || s == "b")
                {
                    temp = 1;        
                }
            }
            else
            {                
                s = s.Replace(" ", "");
                using (StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\\My File3.log"))  
                tw.WriteLine(s);
                temp = 0;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read and write at the same iteration to the same file.
Here a solution using StringBuilder (with him you can manipulate chars in the string):

```
using (StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"file1.txt"))
        {


            using (System.IO.TextReader tr = File.OpenText((@"file.txt")))
            {
                string line;
                StringBuilder items = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    items.Append(line);
                    items.Replace("a ", "a");
                    items.Replace("b ", "b");
                    tw.WriteLine(items);
                    items.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
```